# How can I pop up a div while hovering <a> tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have troubling with showing a div while hovering a `<a>` tag , I could not solve the problem, my code is here in [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jo_basterd/MQr5g/37/).

The `<a>` tag will be visible, while I click or hover on `<a>` tag the div below it should be visible.

Part of my code is like this :

```
<a class="search dropbox_btn" title="Ara" href="#drop-search" id="tour-search">Ara</a>
```

How can I do it with CSS, JavaScript or jQuery?

UPDATE: I want to show the div below:

```
<div id="pill_identifier_fmt">
```

Comment: which div you want to show?

Comment: Please specify your problem little more clear to help you.

Comment: can you shorten your code  and show only part which  is causing problem in jsfiddle

Comment: Just <a> tag will be visible, when i hover on it, the div below should be seen.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2CqsK/ lol its too easy to do ... and better approach will be sid M;s answer

Comment: Gone through your code. It took me a lot of time to understand. Please shorten the code. If I'm reading it right, you should not have a form displayed on rollover since it is expected that when the div is visible some interactions will take place on the form fields.

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/2CqsK/4/

Answer (score 0):

Try this to hide and show div on hover of anchor tag.

```
$('.search').hover(
    function() {
         $('#pill_identifier_fmt').show(1000)}, 
    function(){
         $('#pill_identifier_fmt').hide(1000)}
);
```

**Update:**

If you just want to show the div after hovering not hide it,then you can do this

```
 $('.search').hover(
        function() {
             $('#pill_identifier_fmt').show(1000)}
    );
```

Comment: Your solution works, but i cant do any fucntion on div, it is closing automaticaly, how can i make it do not close while i am hovering on it?

Comment: @user3647419 have you checked my jsfiddle link in comment ?

Comment: Same problem on your solution @NullPoiиteя

Comment: @user3647419 : If you just want to show the div after hovering not hide it,then you can try the updated code.

Answer (score 0):

Pure CSS solution:

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/niranjan_borawake/MQr5g/38/)**

```
#pill_identifier_fmt{
    display:none;
}
#tour-search:hover + div#pill_identifier_fmt{
   display:block;
}
#pill_identifier_fmt:hover{
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using *jQuery*, you can add the code below. The advantage is that the form won't disappear the moment you hover away from the `<a>` tag.

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/MQr5g/43)

CSS:

```
.showAlways {
    display: block;
}
.showHover {
    display: none;
}
.showHover:hover {
    display: block;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#pill_identifier_fmt').addClass('showHover');
    $('#tour-search').hover(function() {
        $('#pill_identifier_fmt').addClass('showAlways');
        $('#pill_identifier_fmt').removeClass('showHover');
    }, function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#pill_identifier_fmt').addClass('showHover');
            $('#pill_identifier_fmt').removeClass('showAlways')
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this, **[DEMO Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shaun1ak/MQr5g/42/)**. If you wish you perform action on the form, this is the solution.

*a#tour-search* finds an `<a>` tag with id 'tour-search'. If you have multiple `<a>` tags use this. Else just `$('a')` would be fine.

```
$("a#tour-search").hover(function(){
   $("#pill_identifier_fmt").css("display","block");

});
```

OR

```
$("a#tour-search").hover(function(){
   $("#pill_identifier_fmt").show();

});
```

If you have multiple `<a>` tags

```
$("a").hover(function(){
   $(this).closest('div').show();

});
```

Comment: it doesn't hide when mouse moves away from anchor

Comment: @SidM OP did not mention hiding the `<div>`, just showing the `<div>` is the problem.! Please check comments on the answers above.